# Some commands not executing in shell-script when using crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

I have shell-script for restart some service in ruby file, kill process and run, and it's work. I want to run this shell-script every hour, so I put commands bash to crontab, cron running every hour but my shell-script only execute kill process, the three last command which is run 3 ruby files doesn't execute.

restart.sh

```
sudo pkill -9 -f '/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby /home/myuser/subscribe.rb'
sudo pkill -9 -f '/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby /home/myuser/retry1.rb'
sudo pkill -9 -f '/home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby /home/myuser/retry2.rb'
sleep .5
nohup /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby /home/myuser/subscribe.rb &!
nohup /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby /home/myuser/retry1.rb &!
nohup /home/myuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby /home/myuser/retry2.rb &!
```

crontab

```
0 */1 * * * bash -lc "/home/myuser/restart.sh"
```

Comment: Your crontab command should just be `0 * * * *  bash -lc "/home/myuser/restart.sh"` for every hour starting at 0 minute.

Comment: @Terrance The problem isn't about scheduler in crontab ([every hour](https://crontab.guru/#0_*/1_*_*_*)) . I have problem with 3 last command in my script which is run 3 ruby files not execute if i'm using cron.

Comment: I don't recall bash having `&!` operator, it should be just `&`.

Comment: Honestly there is no need for the /1 https://crontab.guru/every-1-hour.  But that is beside the point.  I agree with @SergiyKolodyazhnyy here about having the ! at the end of your line.  Did you try your script outside of crontab just to make sure it even works?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I have try remove `!`  it still doesn't work

Comment: @Terrance yes, I have try outside cron, which is `./restart.sh`, and the script worsk fine

Comment: @itx   Another thing, if a process is running under your user, you don't have to use `sudo`, and that might be also blocking the script because it's waiting for your password. Try removing that.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Actually, my scripts have the & but not the nohup.

Comment: @Terrance  Well, on second thought `&` is fine there without `nohup`. There's cases for that, but I think you're right - for just non blocking execution `&` is fine if there's no controlling terminal. I stand corrected.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Thinking about your other comment, I am thinking the sudo could be blocking here.

Comment: @itx OK, try removing `sudo` from first 3 lines and run the script.  Also keep the last `nohup` lines without `!` , the `!` is unnecessary there anyway

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy try removing `sudo` from first 3 lines and remove `!`, still doesn't work. :/

Comment: I do have one question here, why are you running the command with `bash -lc`?  You could probably get away with the first line in your script as `#!/bin/bash` so there would be no need to call bash outside of the script.  Just trying to think of all possibilities as to why the script is not working properly.

Comment: @itx OK.  Does the script have executive permissions ? You're running it as command because in `bash -c '/path/to/script.sh'` , the `-c` will treat it as set of commands.  If a command/file doesn't have executable permissions it won't run. Try changing it to `bash /home/myuser/restart.sh`

Comment: @Terrance Good point. Ideally the script should have just `#!/bin/bash` at the top AND executable permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.

The point of problem isn't permission but in a different shell environment than cron is executing in, especially run ruby file.

Since I'm use `rvm` for manage ruby versions, so I found example

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# load rvm ruby
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.1@projectX

bundle install
ruby /path/to/script.rb
rake do something
```

source : https://rvm.io/integration/cron#example-script

So, I have modified my shell-script looks like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo pkill -9 -f 'ruby /home/myuser/subscribe.rb'
sudo pkill -9 -f 'ruby /home/myuser/retry1.rb'
sudo pkill -9 -f 'ruby /home/myuser/retry2.rb'
sleep .5
source /home/mysuser/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.4.0
nohup ruby /home/myuser/subscribe.rb &
nohup ruby /home/myuser/retry1.rb &
nohup ruby /home/myuser/retry2.rb &
```